# How can I make the 'Baut' object stick randomly to both 'TempatBaut' and 'TempatBaut2'?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 Object, their name :

1. Obeng = The Object that bring "Baut"
2. Baut = The Object I want to move with "Obeng" to Target
3. TempatBaut = Target Of Baut
4. TempatBaut2 = Other Target Of Baut

when i grab "Obeng" and get close to "Baut", they will stick each other (of course they have collider). Then when i bring them to "TempatBaut", the Object "Baut" will stick to "TempatBaut". But i want Object "Baut" can stick more than 1 Target. I want Baut can stick randomly to "TempatBaut" or "TempatBaut2.

note: *I MADE IN UNITY USING C#

MY SCRIPT :

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotasiObengBautUjiCoba : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool baut_masih_di_obeng = false;
    private bool sudah_ditempat_baut = false;

    [Header("Titik Baut")]
    public Transform Baut;

    [Header("Target Baut")]
    public Transform Obeng;

    [Header("Tempat Baut")]
    public Transform TempatBaut;
    public Transform TempatBaut2;

    [Header("Sound")]
    public AudioSource suaraPlug;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "Baut")
        {
            suaraPlug.Play();
        }
    }


    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.name == "Baut")
        {
            if (!this.baut_masih_di_obeng)
            {
                Baut.position = Obeng.position;
                Baut.rotation = Obeng.rotation;
            }
            else if (!this.sudah_ditempat_baut)
            {
                other.transform.position = TempatBaut.position;
                other.transform.rotation = TempatBaut.rotation;

                sudah_ditempat_baut = true;
            }
        }

        if (other.name == "TempatBaut")
        {
            this.baut_masih_di_obeng = true;
        }
    }
}```

i want Object "Baut" can stick more than 1 Target. I want Baut can stick randomly to "TempatBaut" or "TempatBaut2.
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gameObject tags for this.

Create a gameObject tag called "Obeng" and another tag called "TargetOfBaut". In the Obeng gameObject, set the tag to "Obeng", and in the TempatBaut and TempatBaut2 gameObjects set their tag to "TargetOfBaut". Using this to tags you can control how to stick the Baut gameObject

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Obeng")
    {
        baut_masih_di_obeng = true;
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "TargetOfBaut")
    {
        sudah_ditempat_baut = true;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Obeng")
    {
        baut_masih_di_obeng = false;
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "TargetOfBaut")
    {
        sudah_ditempat_baut = false;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Obeng" && !this.sudah_ditempat_baut)
    {
        Baut.position = Obeng.position;
        Baut.rotation = Obeng.rotation;
    }
    else if (other.gameObject.tag == "TargetOfBaut")
    {
        Baut.position = other.gameObject.position;
        Baut.rotation = other.gameObject.rotation;
    }
}
```